# Reassigning values in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying to write a game of Yahtzee as part of an online course (not actually enrolled, just playing along at home) I have hit a bit of a wall manipulating values in the array that keeps track of the dice values. This is the section of code that seems to be causing trouble;

```
for (int i=0; i<N_DICE; i++){                  //goes through each die.
     if (display.isDieSelected(i) == false){  //checks if player wants to reroll the die.
     dice [i] = dice[i];//problem line-should reassign the same value back to the die.
     }
     else {
         dice [i] = rgen.nextInt(1, 6);
     }
}
```

Assigning a new random number works, and if I roll all 5 dice every turn its happy.

I've changed the offending line to dice[i]=1 for testing purposes and while it takes some fun out of the game, the program works, so I'm thinking its something simple I'm doing wrong with that line.

I've tried assigning dice[i] to a temp variable (inside and out of the if loop) and then assigning temp back to dice[i].
I've tried just leaving the if loop empty.
I've tried setting it up as a multi dimesional array with a seperate array for each roll.
I've tried adding a cast (didnt think that'd do it but I was out of ideas).
All of these have had the same results.
Only been programming a few weeks, I'd be very gratefull if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This site rocks, problem sorted in ten minutes! Roland Illig is this weeks winner, a missing "final" was the issue. Thank you everyone for your input and thanks to Don for edditing my message down so people could read it!

Comment: +1 for Yahtzee - its a great game

Comment: Please accept your favorite answer by clicking on the tick next to the answer

Comment: @ghostJago Not the way I've written it..  thanks for the heads up, it wont let me upvote useful answers but I've accepted Ronalds answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks completely correct, although I would write it a bit more compactly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N_DICE; i++) {
  if (display.isDieSelected(i)) {
    dice[i] = rgen.nextInt(1, 6);
  }
}
```

So your problem probably lies somewhere else. Is `dice` a new array, or is it always the same in the program? If it is a field in some class, it should have the `final` modifier, like this:

```
public class YahtzeeState {

  private final int[] dice = new int[N_DICE];

}
```

This declaration makes sure that the `dice` array cannot be replaced later with a completely different array. The values in the array can still be changed though.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do with that line:

```
dice[i] = dice[i];
```

Since it's a NOP, why not just omit it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the purpose of:

```
dice[i] = dice[i]
```

Can't you just use something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<N_DICE; i++){                  
     if (display.isDieSelected(i)){  
         dice [i] = rgen.nextInt(1, 6);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the dice-array initialized? I don't know your entire code but I could imagine that it doesn't work because the dice-array gets it values only in this loop?

Maybe you should try something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<N_DICE; i++){                  
 if (display.isDieSelected(i) || dice[i] == null)
     dice [i] = rgen.nextInt(1, 6);
```

}